# The patient is 'through'

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> After the treatment, the patient is through except for follow-up.

What does *through* mean in the above— recovered from the sickness? What about 'except for follow-up'?

Answer (score 2):

*through* here means "done". That is to say, the patient is done with the treatment process, except for any possible follow-up appointments, presumably so that the doctor can check up on how the patient is doing after the treatment.

Comment: But of course, "through" has a number of different meanings, some which do not offer a particularly rosy view of the patient's future.